# if else and includes

Tags: php

I have a conditional include but running into an issue.

For example, this works

```
<?php if($t==3)
echo 'Foo';
    else
echo 'Foo something else';
    ?>
```

and this: doesn't work

```
<?php if($t==3)
echo 'Foo';
include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_one.php');
echo 'Example: one';
    else
echo 'Foo something else';
include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_two.php');
echo 'Example: two';
 ?>
```

Could you shed some light as to what I am doing wrong?

Or should I include the echoes within the include and just do echo include ...blah else echo another include ...

Comment: I'm surprised the first example works

Comment: @Paul: Nasty indentation but nothing special. Almost every language with curly braces allows you to omit them for control statements if the block just contains a single statement.

Comment: @paul why? are you surprised?

Comment: learn something new every day! Didn't know that. I always though you needed the `{}` no matter what.

Comment: @Paul, you can even do it like: echo ($t==3) ? 'Foo' : 'Bar';   :)

Comment: @Paul: You don't need the `{}`, but it's a good idea to use them always.  Prevents mistakes like this :-P

Comment: @Zuul - yeah, I knew about that, I just thought `if else` statements needed `{}` Thanks

Comment: @Paul: It's more like this: The statement that follows the `if` gets executed when the condition is true. So in order to execute *multiple* statements, you have to use another statement (at least in some languages the block is a statement too (afaik)) (`{...}`) to group them into one statement. Have a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php (yeah, some for `if...else`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `{}` when your blocks inside the `if/else` are more than one line.

```
<?php
if($t==3){
    echo 'Foo';
    include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_one.php');
    echo 'Example: one';
}
else{
    echo 'Foo something else';
    include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_two.php');
    echo 'Example: two';
}
?>
```

You should use `{}` anyway, it makes it easier to read, and prevents mistakes like this.

Comment: @422 also a small, but simple advice write if-statements like `constant == $variable`. This holds especially true where if-statements accept non-boolean values. (C/C++, PHP, Javascript). So that if you accidently write only one `=` you won't get an assignment (and probably pass the IF statement). So write your if like `if(3 == $t)` or `if(3 === $t)` if your $t value has to be a numerical value.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the { } that are used to group several lines within the if else:

```
<?php

if ($t==3) {

  // run all of this is $t equals 3
  echo 'Foo';
  include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_one.php');
  echo 'Example: one';

} else {

  // otherwise, run this
  echo 'Foo something else';
  include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_two.php');
  echo 'Example: two';

}

// runs every time
echo "test me, I always run";

?>
```

Comment: sweet thanks :) It just had to be something obvious huh, thankyou for the last bit.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($t==3)
{
  echo 'Foo';
  include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_one.php');
  echo 'Example: one';
}
else
{
  echo 'Foo something else';
  include ('/home/path/public_html/includes/foo_two.php');
  echo 'Example: two';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is 100% correct, BUT...

It's not mandatory to use curly braces {} everywhere. This code might look like

```
if ($t==3):
    // code
else:
    // code
endif;
```

So `:` and closing `endif` needed